# Does the Bias-Reducing Properties of Including Outcome Predictors as Covariates Apply Outside of Regression?

Tags: regression, causality

The primary purpose of selection on observables identification strategies is to adjust for confounders to estimate a causal effect (assuming ignorability somehow holds). However, researchers can adjust for covariates that are not confounders without hurting causal estimates. The best example of this that I can think of is the predictor of outcome. Adjusting for a predictor of outcome does not do anything for improving a causal estimate ([Cinelli et al. 2022](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r493.pdf)). But adjusting for a predictor of outcome can possibly increase precision. Put another way, including a predictor of outcome has the possibility to increase power ([Wysocki et al. 2022](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/25152459221095823)).

From these observations, I have two questions:

First, does the precision-increasing elements of adjusting for a predictor of outcome apply only within regression adjustment settings? That is, if I adjust for a predictor of outcome on the right-hand side of a regression equation, does it have the same precision-increasing properties as if I was to match on the predictor of outcome?

Second, in small-ish sample size setting (N <= 5K), is it ever truly legitimate to consider adjusting for a predictor of outcome given the curse of dimensionality? Or would the better course of action be to simply adjust for confounders unless there is strong reason to adjust for a predictor of outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the observation that adjusting for pre-treatment predictors of the outcome that are not confounders increases precision also holds for other methods of adjustment, like matching and weighting. See [Brookhart et al. (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwj149) for an investigation into this. [Williamson et al. (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.5991) also show how adjusting for prognostic variables through propensity score weighting can increase precision in randomized experiments (i.e., when there are no confounders).

The impact of adjusting for a covariate on the precision of the effect estimate depends on interactions between the sample size, the number of variables already in the model, the variability in the outcome, and the effect of the covariate on the outcome. In some cases adding such a variable increases precision, and in others it doesn't. There are no simple rules for this. I would not say all samples of size less than 5000 are small; indeed, I would say 5000 is quite large in some fields. For a small sample, adjusting for prognostic variables in critical to achieve the precision required to detect effects, even more so than in large samples.

[Rao (1971)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2686082) gives a precise condition for when including a prognostic variable improves precision: when the coefficient of the included covariate is larger than its (true) standard error, its inclusion reduces the variance of all other coefficients in the model. In practice, we don't know a coefficient's true standard error because the residual variance is estimated, but this yields a heuristic of retaining any prognostic variables with a t-statistic greater than 1 in absolute value. Of course, this involves having already fit the outcome model. Repeated fitting the outcome model and making choices about covariate adjustment after already estimating the effect can be seen as a form of snooping and is one reason to use substantive knowledge to adjust for only the most predictive covariates without engaging in a specification search. Or you can use an asymptotically efficient method like TMLE and not worry too much about this.

Comment: Is the increase in precision real, though? Is it true knowledge, or only an illusion?

Comment: It's real! The true standard error is lower, and the estimated standard error reflects that. The Rao article uses proofs.

Comment: Hmm. If there are proofs, there are proofs, but this seems extremely counter-intuitive: why should variables that are ostensibly not causally related provide any additional insight into a process?